# How to send values from dynamically created text boxes to oracle database using spring mvc 3?

Tags: javascript, spring, oracle, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to send values from the dynamically created text boxes(i.e i have created a add button option using java script which add a new text box when user click on it. Please let me know if any one knows the answer.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do the header & tags contain more information than the question body?

Comment: Since this is my first question in this site, so bare with me..If you need any info, i will provide

Comment: Well, it is the responsibility of the person who asks the question to make the question clear. I don't _need_ any info, I just noted it is hard to understand the specific question you have. This may mean you need to elaborate.

Comment: use AJAX to send data from dynamically created text boxes to controller and process your database transaction there.. **better show the code what have you done so far?**